# Apache hosted Python Flask web app running in Rocky Linux 9 not able execute shutdown command

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, wsgi, rocky-os

I'm new to Python Flask application web hosting, in the web app I'm trying to set functionality to shutdown server once every work is complete. I have built the application in Flask Jinja Python virtual environment and hosted by wsgi using Apache web service. User `apache` is having root privileges to execute the script, and complete permissions.

The whole Rocky Linux OS is running in Raspberry Pi4

**Problem**

When I try the below options to shutdown which is hosted by Apache, I'm getting below error in Apache error_log file.

```
sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied
sudo: unable to open audit system: Permission denied
sudo: a password is required
```

**python **init**.py file**

```
data = 'yes'
down(data)

def down(cname = None):
    try:
        if cname == 'yes':
            print (cname)
            if os.name != 'nt':
                #os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")
                #os.system('sudo systemctl poweroff')
                #subprocess.check_output("sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
                subprocess.call(["sudo", "shutdown", "-h", "now"])
                #os.system('sudo bash [complete path to the script]/off.ksh')
                #os.system('python [complete path to the script]/test.py')
                #subprocess.run(["python", "[complete path to the script]/test.py"])

            else :
               os.system('shutdown /s')
            return

except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        e = str(e) + str(exc_type) + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        return Exception(e)
```

**off.ksh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo shutdown -h now
```

**test.py**

```
import os

if os.name != 'nt':
    print(os.name)
    os.system('sudo shutdown -h now')
else :
    os.system('shutdown /s')`
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: is anything have to do with Selinux in Rocky Linux 9?

Comment: You don't want your main web service to be able to call `sudo`, for security reasons. It would be better to run a separate system service as root, and it calls shutdown when it gets a message of some kind (e.g. a new file in a directory).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by doing something nasty in permissions, but so far, possible.

Set in `sudoes` the `user` that will execute this script, as show below

```
your_username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: This does not help, still same issue. any other suggestions

Comment: did you set the same user that you get by ps -ef for flask ?

Comment: yes, apache is the user as it is available in wheel and root group, this flask is a pip package of python

Comment: try su - <this user> and run `shutdown -h now`

Comment: as it is hosted in apache wsgi web service, su - username command is not helping, and it prompts password, which cannot be entered without logging in.